# Unhiding Activity Bar in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidently Hid Activity Bar while working in VS code. I don't know how to open Activity Bar Again, but need Activity Bar for develop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is:

> View -> Appearance -> Show Activity bar